# center a text next to an image

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, center

I have a screen called Tools, which allows me to redirect my user to multiple child screens.
I want to align the text in the middle of the image. I got to do this:

[image: tools screen]

But I have the impression that it is not perfectly aligned in the center, an offset is created, I do not know if you can see it.

Could you give me your help on this point, how can I improve this?

The code :

```
export default function Tools({navigation}) {

  return (
    <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16}}>{i18n.t("tools.action.account")}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Account')}
          style={styles.roundButton}>
          <Image source={require("../../assets/images/accounting.png")} style={styles.img}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Scan')}
          style={styles.roundButton}>
          <Image source={require("../../assets/images/barcode.png")} style={styles.img}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16}}>{i18n.t("tools.action.scanProducts")}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16}}>{i18n.t("tools.action.ticket")}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Tickets')}
          style={styles.roundButton}>
          <Image source={require("../../assets/images/ticket.png")} style={styles.img}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Checkout')}
          style={styles.roundButton}>
          <Image source={require("../../assets/images/cash-register.png")}
                 style={styles.img}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16}}>{i18n.t("tools.action.cash")}</Text>
      </View>
            <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16}}>{i18n.t("tools.action.products")}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Products')}
          style={styles.roundButton}>
          <Image source={require("../../assets/images/products.png")} style={styles.img}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
   </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

The style :

```
 screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
row: {
   flexDirection: 'row',
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent:'center',
   width : '100%',
 },
roundButton: {
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
  },
  img: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
```

Comment: Text Over Image?

Comment: Thank you for answering me, sorry if it is not clear. No, I want the text to be roughly the same place it is now but really aligned in the middle of the yellow 'circle'. If we look, an offset is created as we go, the text is not perfectly in the middle of the image.
(in fact I don't find it super visible but that's what I was asked to correct, but I don't know in which direction to go)

Comment: and if you change `alignItems: 'center` by `alignItems: 'baseline'` in `row`?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, but where you added `* { outline: 1px dashed #000 }`?

Comment: Try with: img: {
    width: 50,
    height: 58,
  }, I guess your 50 height is limiting the height of your block and the text is just written by the bottom of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `marginTop` from `roundButton`:

```
 roundButton: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
  },
```

Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/ranting-cookies)

[image]

I added pink background just to highlight the row and show that text is centered, remove it later :)

Full Source Code:

```js
export default function Tools({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16 }}>
            {('tools.action.account')}
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Account')}
            style={styles.roundButton}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vJf.jpg?s=328&g=1"}}
              style={styles.img}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Scan')}
            style={styles.roundButton}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vJf.jpg?s=328&g=1"}}
              style={styles.img}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16 }}>
            {('tools.action.scanProducts')}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16 }}>
            {('tools.action.ticket')}
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.roundButton}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vJf.jpg?s=328&g=1"}}
              style={styles.img}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.roundButton}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vJf.jpg?s=328&g=1"}}
              style={styles.img}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16 }}>
            {('tools.action.cash')}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 16 }}>
            {('tools.action.products')}
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.roundButton}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vJf.jpg?s=328&g=1"}}
              style={styles.img}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: "pink",
    margin: 5
  },

  roundButton: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
  },
  img: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out and show me this way, it's really kind and awesome! Thank you !
I also add <ScrollView contentContainerStyle = {{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}> to be able to have the whole centered.